# Python...Tkinter collisions

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I have been trying to figure out a collision detection. So far I have managed to code it in a way that the collision is detected when the projectile touches a left bottom corner of the enemy. I want the collision to be detected when the bottom of the rectangle is hit.

The collision detection is handled in the `move_shot()`

Here is the entire code

```
from tkinter import *
# creates window
window = Tk()
size = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.title("This is a window")
# set up geometry using string formatting operator %
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1000, 1000, 10, 10))
window.update()
# creates canvas
global canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, bg='green')
# pack is a layout manager
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.update()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 1000, 1000, 0, fill="orange", width=10, outline="white", tag="border")

def shooting():
    global loaded_gun

    c = canvas.coords("player")
    canvas.create_line(c[0],c[1] + 20,c[2],c[3],width=5,fill="yellow",tag="shot")
    loaded_gun = 0
    move_shot("shot") # furas


def move_shot(name):

    canvas.move(name,0,-10)
    canvas.update()
    window.after(50, move_shot, "shot") # furas

    global loaded_gun

    ran = len(enemies)

    if loaded_gun == 0:
        for x in range(0,ran):

            shot = canvas.coords(name)
            en = canvas.coords(enemies[x])




            if shot[0] == en[0] and shot[0] <= en[0] + 70:
                if shot[1] <= en[1] + 70:
                    #print(canvas.coords(enemies[x]))
                    canvas.delete(enemies[x])
                    #print(canvas.coords(name))
                    enemies.remove(enemies[x])
                    canvas.delete(name)
                    loaded_gun = 1
                    break





def on_key_press(event):

    global canvas,loaded_gun


    c = canvas.coords("player")

    if event.keysym == 'Left' and c[0] > 0:
        canvas.move("player", -20,0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right' and c[2] < 1000:
        canvas.move("player", 20, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        if loaded_gun == 1:
            shooting()
    elif event.keysym == 'Shift_L':
        loaded_gun = 1
        canvas.delete("shot")

def draw_enemy():
    c = [100,100,170,170]
    inc = 100

    global enemies

    enemies = []

    for x in range(0,8):
        for y in range(0,4):
            enemy = canvas.create_rectangle(c[0] + inc * x,c[1] + inc * y,c[2] + inc * x,c[3] + inc * y,fill="red",tag="enemy")
            enemies.append(enemy)

def move_enemy():
    canvas.move("enemy",0,20)
    window.after(1000, move_enemy) # furas


canvas.create_line(500, 950,500,1000, width=15, fill="red",tag="player")

loaded_gun = 1

draw_enemy()

window.bind_all('<Key>', on_key_press) # furas

move_shot("shot") # furas
move_enemy() # furas

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: if `shot[0] == en[0]` then automaticly `shot[0] <= en[0] + 70` too. Basic Math.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out how to python for past 7 hours. My brain can not do basic math any longer...

Comment: Well, I'm looking on it but I have few other answers to finish at the same time :)

Comment: At that moment I can say don't check if shot touch rectangle strictly because always there is few pixels difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems detection works OK. Almost nothing to do.

I only remove shot when it leave the screen.

And I check `loaded_gun == 0:` before I run `after()` again.
if you keep running `after loop` next shot will have two `after loop` and it will run 2 times faster . Thrird shot will run 3 times faster.

I add `# furas` in places I changed.

```
from Tkinter import *

# creates window
window = Tk()
size = window.winfo_screenheight()
window.title("This is a window")

# set up geometry using string formatting operator %
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1000, 1000, 10, 10))
window.update()

# creates canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, bg='green')

# pack is a layout manager
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.update()
canvas.create_rectangle(0, 1000, 1000, 0, fill="orange", width=10, outline="white", tag="border")

def shooting():
    global loaded_gun

    c = canvas.coords("player")
    canvas.create_line(c[0],c[1] + 20,c[2],c[3],width=5,fill="yellow",tag="shot")
    loaded_gun = 0

    move_shot("shot")


def move_shot(name):
    global loaded_gun

    canvas.move(name,0,-10)
    canvas.update()

    if loaded_gun == 0:
        shot = canvas.coords(name) # furas

        for x in enemies: # furas

            en = canvas.coords(x) # furas

            if en[0] <= shot[0] <= en[0] + 70: # furas
                if shot[1] <= en[1] + 70: # furas
                    #print(canvas.coords(enemies[x]))
                    canvas.delete(x) # furas
                    #print(canvas.coords(name))
                    enemies.remove(x) # furas
                    canvas.delete(name)
                    loaded_gun = 1
                    break

        if shot[1] < 0: # furas
            canvas.delete(name) # furas
            loaded_gun = 1 # furas

    if loaded_gun == 0: # furas
        window.after(50, move_shot, "shot")


def on_key_press(event):
    global canvas,loaded_gun

    c = canvas.coords("player")

    if event.keysym == 'Left' and c[0] > 0:
        canvas.move("player", -20,0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right' and c[2] < 1000:
        canvas.move("player", 20, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'space':
        if loaded_gun == 1:
            shooting()
    elif event.keysym == 'Shift_L':
        loaded_gun = 1
        canvas.delete("shot")

def draw_enemy():
    global enemies

    c = [100,100,170,170]
    inc = 100

    enemies = []

    for x in range(8):
        for y in range(4):
            enemy = canvas.create_rectangle(c[0] + inc * x, c[1] + inc * y,c[2] + inc * x,c[3] + inc * y,fill="red",tag="enemy")
            enemies.append(enemy)

def move_enemy():
    canvas.move("enemy", 0, 20)
    window.after(1000, move_enemy) # furas

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

canvas.create_line(500, 950,500,1000, width=15, fill="red",tag="player")

loaded_gun = 1

draw_enemy()

window.bind_all('<Key>', on_key_press) # furas

move_shot("shot") # furas
move_enemy() # furas

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well nevermind

I have figured it out I just needed to do this

```
if shot[0] >= en[0] and shot[0] <= en[0] + 70:
```

Comment: Thanks furas...you have been my lifesaver this evening :D